# What do plugin-generated tab names mean?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

I've long wondered if the cryptic tab names that some plugins generate have meaning. For example, [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gstatus` opens a new tab with the name `f///h/r/g/r/.g//`, and [coc-fzf](https://github.com/antoinemadec/coc-fzf) with `g:coc_fzf_preview_fullscreen` set opens new tabs with names like `t//~/g/r/c//2/h/r/.l/s/n/p/f/b/f/h/r/.l/s/n/p/f/b/p/t/n/31;#FZF`. If this is documented anywhere, I've been unable to find it.

Comment: I don't know about fugitive or coc-fzf as I don't use them, but for regular files it uses the first letter of the path name, so `vim foo/bar/file` shows up as `f/b/file`. I image it's something similar for those plugins?

Comment: @martin-tournoij I think that gets me most of the way there. I can decode the fugitive name as `fugitive///home/randy/git/REPO_STARTING_WITH_R/.git//`. Not sure what the trailing `/` is about. The coc-fzf preview is a terminal window, so probably `terminal//~/git/REPO/SUB_PROJECT_STARTING_WITH_C`. After that there's a `2` that might be "two more things" and then two parts that decode as `/home/randy/.local/share/nvim/plugged/...` and then go further into specific plugin directory hierarchies, eventually to executables. There's some stuff after one that might be args or something.

Comment: `:h pathshorten()`